# Haskell Maybe type constructor

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a very simple implementation of the `Maybe` type constructor in the context of passing an integer into a function, and getting a `Maybe a` type out.

The specific case I am looking at is a function which takes in an integer and returns whether that number is in some bound.

```
data Maybe Number = Nothing | Just FirstRange | Just SecondRange | Just ThirdRange | Just FourthRange | Just FifthRange
   deriving(Show)
checknum :: Integer -> Maybe Number
checknum numinput
    |numinput >=0 && < 50 = Just FirstRange
    |numinput >=50 && < 60 = Just SecondRange
    |numinput >=60 && < 70 = Just ThirdRange
    |numinput >=70 && < 80 = Just FourthRange
    |numinput >=80 && < 100 = Just FifthRange
    |numinput < 0 || numinput > 100 = Nothing
```

However, this implementation just gives me an error:

```
Unexpected type 'Number' in the data declaration for 'Maybe'
A data declaration should have form
 data Maybe a = ...
```

Comment: Unrelated: if you want to be sure to cover all possible cases, use ` | otherwise = Nothing` as the very last guard. Using instead a hand-crafted guard which complements all the previous guards is more error prone.

Answer (score 5):

No need to define `Maybe`, just define your `Number` type which then substitutes the "a" in `Maybe a`:

```
data Number = FirstRange | SecondRange | ThirdRange | FourthRange | FifthRange
```

Also, you are missing a few `numinput <`.

Comment: Why don't I need to explicitly type construct with Maybe?

Comment: @jamesmartini `Maybe` is a parametrized type, so it takes in an existing type to give you a type. That means that if you define the `Number` type as in this answer, you can apply `Maybe` to it to get `Maybe Number`. You can use it with any existing type and it will work.

Comment: @jamesmartini `Maybe` is already defined by the standard library, as `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` -- you do not have to redefine it. If you replace `a` with `Number` (i.e., if you use `Maybe Number`) you will get exactly what you need.